# Pizza add Toppings partially filled array java

Tags: java

[image]

I don't know to add a new topping name to my array and the end i have to add elements but i just don't know where to use a loop so far i have this in my code .. thanks-- The idea behind this project is that you will use a partially filled array to maintain a selection of pizza toppings.There will be a fixed list of available toppings that the user can select from. The user will be able to add/remove toppings from their list of toppings this is the output :

```
Currently no toppings selected
Enter Option: (A-Add Topping; R-Remove Topping; X-Exit): a
Possible toppings are:
0 Sausage
1 Pepper
2 Pepperoni
3 Brocolli  didn’t realize I misspelled it until pasting into Word…sigh
4 Tomatoes
5 Eggplant
6 Meatballs
7 Ham
8 Pineapple
9 Bacon
Enter # of topping to add: 6
Toppings Selected:
0 Meatballs
Enter Option: (A-Add Topping; R-Remove Topping; X-Exit): a
Possible toppings are:
0 Sausage
1 Pepper
2 Pepperoni
3 Brocolli
4 Tomatoes
5 Eggplant
6 Meatballs
7 Ham
8 Pineapple
9 Bacon
Enter # of topping to add: 0
Toppings Selected:
0 Meatballs
1 Sausage
Enter Option: (A-Add Topping; R-Remove Topping; X-Exit): a
Possible toppings are:
0 Sausage
```

my code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pizzatopfinal_v01;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class PizzaTopFinal_v01 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        showDisplay();




       // }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));

    }   //end of main method 


    public static void addTopping(int numTopp){
    String[] topping = { "Sausage"," Pepper"," Pepperoni",
            "Brocolli", "Tomatoes"," Eggplant",
            "Meatballs"," Ham"," Pineapple"," Bacon"};

        int topp= numTopp;
        System.out.println("Topping selected:");                

        String name; 
        name = topping[topp]; 
        final int length  = 100;
        String[] newToppingArray = new String[length];
        int size=0;

        newToppingArray[size]=name;
        System.out.println(size + "\t" + newToppingArray[size]);
        size++;
        showDisplay();

        //for(int size=0;size<newToppingArray.length;size++)
        //System.out.println(topping[topp]);

    } // end of method addTopping 

    public static void showDisplay(){

    String input;

        System.out.println("Currently no toppings selected");
        System.out.print("Enter option: (A-Add Topping; R-Remove Topping "
                + "; X-Exit):");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Possible toppings are:");
        System.out.println("0 Sausage");
        System.out.println("1 Pepper");
        System.out.println("2 Pepperoni");
        System.out.println("3 Brocolli");
        System.out.println("4 Tomatoes");
        System.out.println("5 Eggplant");
        System.out.println("7 Ham");
        System.out.println("8 Pineapple");
        System.out.println("9 Bacon"); 

     if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            //System.out.println("you selected add topping");
            System.out.print("Enter # of topping to add :");

            //create a Scanner object to hold the number option 
            int numOfTopping;
            numOfTopping = keyboard.nextInt();
            addTopping(numOfTopping);
            //System.out.println("congrats you enter: "+ numOfTopping);

                                        }
       else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
            System.out.println("You selected Remove topping");
       else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
            System.out.println("You selected Exit Program bye bye ");
       else
           System.out.println("Not valid option! ");
    }



}   //end of the class
```

Comment: Look into using an ArrayList instead of just an array.

Comment: i cant use arraylist i have to use only partially filled array... the problem is that i do not know where to use the loops to keep adding elements to the new array i just dont know